# I can't find a way to make sockets work with react and nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, socket.io

I've already tried everything, but I always get:
GET http://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NPGI2WE 404 (Not Found) polling-xhr.js:203

my server:

```
const express = require("express");
const http = require("http");
const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app)
const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());
app.options('*', cors());
const socketio = require('socket.io')
const io = socketio(server);

io.on("connection", socket => {

    socket.on("welcome", () => {
        console.log("hello");
    })
});


const port = 3000;

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`listen on port ${port}`))
```

in component react

```
import React from 'react'

import io from "socket.io-client";
let socket = io("http://localhost:3000");


export default function Socket() {
    socket.emit("welcome", "hello client");
    return (
        <div>
            <h2>Hello</h2>
        </div>
    )
}
```

react running in "localhost:3001" and nodejs in "localhost:3000"

I no longer know how to do to even manage to connect a simple "hello"

Comment: in your client, it should be `import * as io from "socket.io-client"; io.connect("url")`

Comment: i changed to "  let socket = io.connect("http://localhost:3000"); " but i keep getting the same error

Comment: try with:
import * as io from "socket.io-client";
let socket = io.connect("http://localhost:3000");
but nothing

Comment: Can somebody help me?

Comment: The problem is in your server. Instead of `app.listen` try `server.listen`

Answer (score 1):

The following is working for me,

Server Code :

```
   const express = require("express");
    const http = require("http");
    const app = express();
    const server = http.createServer(app)
    const cors = require('cors');
    app.use(cors());
    app.options('*', cors());
    const socketio = require('socket.io')
    const io = socketio(server);
    
    io.on("connection", socket => {
    
        console.log("Hello connected");
        
        socket.on("welcome", () => {
            console.log("hello");
        })
    });
    
    
    const port = 3000;
    
    server.listen(port, () => console.log(`listen on port ${port}`))
```

Client code :

```
const io =  require("socket.io-client");
let socket = io.connect("http://localhost:3000");

socket.emit("welcome", "connected");
```

Comment: only works with
let socket = io.connect ("http: // localhost: 3001");
and not with "let socket = io.connect (" http: // localhost: 3000 ");"
it's something very strange

Comment: what error do you get when you run server at port `3000` ?